# Space generated in action string

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am building a Asp.Net Core 2.1 EF MVC solution.

Instead of writing separate lines for each CRUD button (Edit, Create, Delete) in each of my Index views, I am trying to generate the buttons dynamically from a partial view as follows.

Models/AdmSchool

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace FACEZ.Models
{
    public partial class AdmSchool
    {
        [Display(Name = "Id")] 
        public int AdmSchoolId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        [Display(Name = "Code")]
        public string AdmSchoolCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "School Name")]
        public string AdmSchoolDescr { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Generic Email Principal")]
        public string EmailPrincipal { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Generic Email Accounts")]
        public string EmailAccounts { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Generic Email Registrar")]
        public string EmailRegistrar { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Obsolete")] 
        public bool Obsolete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Views/Shared/_IndividualButtonPartial

```
@model FACEZ.Models.IndividualButtonPartial
<a type="button" class="btn btn-sm @Model.ButtonType"
   href="@Url.Action(Model.Action) @Model.ActionParameters">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-@Model.Glyph"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">@Model.Text</span>
</a>
```

Views/Shared/_TableButtonPartial

```
@model FACEZ.Models.IndividualButtonPartial

<td style="width: 150px;">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_IndividualButtonPartial",
            new IndividualButtonPartial { 
                Action="Edit",
                ButtonType="btn-primary",
                Glyph = "pencil",
                Text = "Edit",
                Id=Model.Id
            })


        @await Html.PartialAsync("_IndividualButtonPartial",
            new IndividualButtonPartial { 
                Action="Details",
                ButtonType="btn-success",
                Glyph = "list",
                Text = "Details",
                Id=Model.Id
            })


        @await Html.PartialAsync("_IndividualButtonPartial",
            new IndividualButtonPartial { 
                Action="Delete",
                ButtonType="btn-danger",
                Glyph = "trash",
                Text = "Delete",
                Id=Model.Id
            })

    </div>
</td>
```

Areas/Adm/Views/AdmSchools/Index.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.ExpressionTranslators.Internal
@model IEnumerable<FACEZ.Models.AdmSchool>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<div class="form-border">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AdmSchoolCode)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AdmSchoolDescr)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailPrincipal)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailAccounts)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailRegistrar)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Obsolete)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdmSchoolCode)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdmSchoolDescr)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailPrincipal)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailAccounts)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailRegistrar)
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Obsolete)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @await Html.PartialAsync("_TableButtonPartial", new IndividualButtonPartial {Id=item.AdmSchoolId})

                        @*  I am trying to replace the following code with the line above
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.AdmSchoolId">Edit</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.AdmSchoolId">Details</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.AdmSchoolId">Delete</a>
                        *@
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When I run the app, I can see the school info in the Index view.
However, the action link that is being created, is getting a space in it from somewhere?
like https://localhost:44399/Adm/AdmSchools/Edit /1   instead of
like https://localhost:44399/Adm/AdmSchools/Edit/1

How can i remove the space after the action name.

Comment: welcome to SO. please try to shorten your code, providing only the required info. this will help other navigate through the code quicker. for instance, i am don't think your class declaration is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `_IndividualButtonPartial` you do have a space between `@Url.Action(Model.Action)` and `@Model.ActionParameters`. This is what is getting reflected.